# Red Hat no package realmd available

Tags: rhel, software-installation

I would like to use AD authentication with a RHEL server using realmd and SSSD. I tried installing realmd using `yum install realmd` but I get the following message:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security,
              : subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
No package realmd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Same happens when running `yum install adcli`

This is the output of `cat /etc/redhat-release`

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the EPEL repository?  EPEL is not added a default repo.  Add it first then execute yum install adcli.  See http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-x86_64/adcli-0.7.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html  Separately you can download the package and add it to your own repo.

Answer (score 0):

realmd not compatible with RHEL6

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2273711

Answer (score 0):

Which samba version did you use on RHEL 6.7 for AD authentication? Samba 4 got commercial version to support AD Authentication.What I knew AD Autherntication required LDAP and Kerberos Authentication when using Samba for AD Authentication.